# User defined column letter in a Range call

Tags: excel, vba

Asking to user the letter referencing a column ; then using the answer to get the range of this a cell with in this column at some row.
But the "Range" refuses to recognize the letter input.

What am I missing in the following simple two lines ?

```
UserCol = Application.InputBox(" Please enter the column...", Type:=0)
Set Z = Range(UserCol & 5)
```

Comment: Does it work with `Type:=2`?

Comment: Check the value of `UserCol & 5` first, with `Debug.Print` - also, your `Range` is not Fully Qualified (so will fail if the `ActiveSheet` is actually a Chart).  Finally, are you doing any checks/sanitizing on that input?  (For example, what if I type "A1"?  Or, "A1:B"?)

Comment: I am confused by those answers. I have tried all solutions and none work or I misunderstand. If I do not ask a user input and set for example a fixed "H" column everything works correctly.

Comment: It works now using Type 2. I don't know why not working before. I restarted Excel. Maybe why ?
Thanks to all of you for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UserCol = Application.InputBox(" Please enter the column...", Type:=2)
Set Z = Range((UserCol & 5))
```

I set `Type` to **2** to return a string from your user's input ([see her for more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox))

Additionally, I added a parenthesis to the `Range`, because `(UserCol & 5)` becomes e.g. `A5`, and you need `Range(A5)`.

Comment: @Studix Did you also add the extra layer of parenthesis?

Comment: This does work assuming the input is eg "B". You don't need the extra brackets though.

Comment: @Studix - "does not work" is not a helpful response. What are you entering in the box?

Comment: @Studix I have just tested this and can confirm that it DOES work. As does my solution. Assuming you are copying and pasting correctly, you must have other problems elsewhere which you haven't shared with us.

Comment: Yes gravitate, as I mentionned above, it works now after restarting Excel. I don't know why. But using Type 2.
Incidentaly your idea to use Option Explicit is certainly good but if I insert it after the Sub NameOfMacro, it creates an error or I need to remove the name of the macro.

Comment: Ah, that is an odd error. But then I have found Excel to be full of odd errors like that at one time or another. The `Option Explicit` should be placed at the very top of the page, before any subs or functions, because it will apply to all of them.

Comment: But if I write Option Explicit as a first line, and then "Sub MacroName() I get an error "Variable not defined" for this second line. If I define MacroName as string then I get another error "ambiguous name ?

Comment: @Studix it's not giving you the "Variable not defined" for the name of the Sub (MacroName), but instead because you are missing definitions for either "UserCol" or "Z", or both...

Comment: @Studix to further clarify, in Gravitate's answer below, there is a definition for UserCol (`Dim UserCol As String`), but no definition for Z. Try to add `Dim Z As Range` (or alternately: `Dim Z As Variant`)

Comment: I don't think so, because it is the Sub MacroName() line which gets overlined by the debugger

Comment: Prebus, I just see and probe your clarified comment and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Studix Glad to hear it. For information, if the `Sub MacroName()` line is "Overlined" in yellow highlighting, then that can still mean you are missing definitions of something further down. The `Sub MacroName()`line is highlighted because that's where it fails (at the very start)

Comment: So htis means that the debugger cannot pinpoint the missing piece and just highlights the big paragraph. This does not seem as helpful as we could hope ?

Comment: @Studix Exactly - the debugger is meant to be a tool for helping, but it is by no means the ultimate answer. Most times it takes a bit of 'manual digging' as well :)

Comment: @Studix I might be wrong but I think it highlights the function name, because the debugger stops at the point it was running when the error occurs. In this instance, the code was not even running yet, because it was a compile error, rather than a run time error. So the error effectively occurred at the very start. It's not overly helpful, but when you learn what the error messages mean, you will know roughly what to look for.

Comment: Gravitate, at least the error occurred when the non defined variable was met, so  it could highlight it, or the line it is in, instead of the general method it is in. But it is Microsoft, what can you expect else…

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Type:=2`.

Using `Type:=0` will return `="<input string>"`, rather than just `<input string>`.

So, after:

```
Dim UserCol As String
UserCol = Application.InputBox(" Please enter the column...", Type:=2)
```

You can either do:

```
Set Z = Cells(5, UserCol)
```

OR:

```
Set Z = Range(UserCol & "5")
```

I would also suggest that use Option Explicit and also fully qualify range references. e.g. instead of `Set Z = Range(UserCol & "5")`, use `Set Z = Thisworkbook.sheets("MySheetName").Range(UserCol & "5")`

Comment: It does. I have tested this code. Have you also put quotes around the "5"?

Answer (score 0):

This way is easier:

```
Dim UserCol As String
UserCol = Application.InputBox(" Please enter the column...")
Set Z = Cells(5, UserCol)
```

I don't know how did you declare your `UserCol` or if you even declared it. If you didn't and to avoid problems always use `Option Explicit` on the top of your module.

Comment: This would work but because the type is 0, UserCol will contain `="<input>"`, instead of just the string input by the user.

Comment: @Studix try now

Comment: @Prebsus The `Cells` function *does* accept a string, but only for the second argument

Comment: @Chronocidal I do believe you, but I haven't been successful in using it that way myself, plus the docs only list numbers as input (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells). But I'll delete my comment for clarity

Comment: @Prebus : I confirm it works with a string as second argument

Answer (score 0):

This is a *really* simple bug to fix:  `Set Z = Range(UserCol & "5")`

Why?  Because when you use implicit conversion, by typing `UserCol & 5`, VBA includes a space between UserCol and the 5 (and also after the 5).

Here is a test:

```
MsgBox "A" & 5 'Outputs "A 5 "
MsgBox "A" & "5" 'Outputs "A5"
```

(As Gravitate points out, `Application.InputBox(" Please enter the column...", Type:=0)` is a Formula, so an input of "A" would give you `"=""A""`, and not `"A"` -since `"=""A""5"` is not a valid cell reference either, use `Type:=2` for Text or `InputBox(" Please enter the column...")` without the `Application.` or the type filtering)

Comment: Chronocidal, I do not understand your comment : if I Debug print UserCol I get ="H" and no additional space or "

Comment: @Studix Try `Debug.Print UserCol & 5` instead

Comment: With type 2, I get "H"5. So the " " are the problem ? So how to remove them ?

Comment: @Studix By using `type:=2`, [which is the correct type for a String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox#Remarks)